How to prove the positivity of the first eigenfunction of Logarithmic potential operator on $L^2(\Omega)$?
I am considering the operator $$\mathcal{L} u(x)= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_\Omega \log\dfrac{1}{|x-y|}u(y)dy\ \ \text{on} \ \  L^2(\Omega)$$ where $\Omega$ is a bounded domain such that $\mathcal{L}_\Omega$ is a positive operator. Kernel of the operator $\log\frac{1}{|x-y|}$ need not be positive in that domain.
Can we show that there exists a positive eigenfunction corresponding to first eigenvalue(supremum of all eigenvalues)? Or does there exists a counter example of a domain $\Omega$ for which there is no positive eigenfunction?
